# Rails: :case_sensitive => false validation does not take effect on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

so I'm trying to make usernames case_insensitive on my rails app and having added :case_sensitive => false to my development code works just fine but when I push to heroku it doesn't make any bit of difference.

What gives?

any ideas?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :name, presence: true, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
  validates_format_of :email,:with => /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i

  has_many :feeds, :through => :subscriptions, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :subscriptions

  has_secure_password
```

Comment: What database are you using locally? Does the problem also appear when you use a Postgres server on your development machine?

Comment: I am using MySql locally with Postgres on heroku, I really don't want to have to hassle with postgres locally

Comment: Generally speaking, using different databases in development and production is a recipe for pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that since PostgreSQL is inherently case-sensitive, adding the case_insensitive validation to a model has no effect on a Postgresql db backed app

Comment: I am going through the intensely painful process of switching to postgresql, it's awful and I inevitably just decided to upgrade from snow leopard to mountain lion while I was at it.